# Invocation of Post-Method causes "405 Method not allowed"-Error

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish, payara

I I've started a Dynamic Web Project on Eclipse and JAVA EE and try to program a restful service. My Operating System is Windows 7 and the server is Payara.
The problem is, that only "GET" and "OPTIONS" are allowed as http-methods. I tried to change the web.xml so it accepts POST-requests

[web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZFLw.png)
Nevertheless it is still not possible to make a POST-request to the server.
I get a "405 Method not allowed"-Error.And in the response header there is still standing "Allowed: GET, OPTIONS". Is there anything else, that must be done to allow the server to accept POST-requests than to write it into the web.xml-file?

Answer (score 1):

You get the 405 error probably because there is no method in the REST resource that accepts POST request type.
You probably defined only a method annotated with `@GET` and no method annotated with `@POST`. Try adding `@POST` annotation on a method in your REST resource class.

Comment: I already solved the problem: in GlassFish I must set the "Max Post Size" and "Max Save Post Size" from -1 to an appropriate one (8192 in my case). This solved my problem of "402 Method not allowed". The POST resource was already there.

Comment: To get onto configuration page: Configurations->server-config->Network Config->Network Listeners->http-listener-1 ; select tab "http" and then you can play around with settings